# BUG in HDMI showing black screen in frame difference experiment on ZYNQ platform

Tags: sdk, zynq

During the process of implementing the frame difference method experiment on the ZYNQ platform, I encountered the problem of the monitor continuously turning black.

The basic details of my experiment are as follows: this experiment was improved on the case of the ov5640 display experiment in alinx. I have added an image processing module to it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajLXe.png)
My idea is that the frame difference processing module (green box) requires two data inputs, s0 requires the input of the camera's original image data, and s1 data is the previous frame image data read by VDMA2 from DDR3. The processed image in the frame difference processing module (green box) is transmitted to DDR3 again through VDMA1, and then read out and output to HDMI through VDMA0

My question is, I don't know how to configure these three VDMAs to work properly, do their Genlock modes affect each other?
Meanwhile, how can APIs be called in SDKs to use them?

I tried to modify the Genlock mode and channel count of VDMA, as well as modify the code in the SDK, but the output remained black, the indicator light on the monitor was on, and the screen lit up slightly, but there was no image output. I couldn't find the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkd7f.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wfld.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4RYs.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTCLz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnd6V.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceeyp.png)